# What are these "rail-style" LEGO pieces?

Tags: part-identification

I have acquired several large bags of LEGO - most are the tradition bricks, but what kit are these (see photo) rail-type pieces from? They are identified on the reverse with a letter, such as "E", and a 1 or 2-digit number. Some of the rails contain small teeth the entire length - some are smooth.

[image]

Comment: Related: [What different types of train tracks exist](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/2885/10369)

Comment: That gear doesn't look like Lego at all. But those rails where the normal rails in the 70's

Comment: @Tonny , The gear is [part # 743 :Technic, Gear Samsonite 35 Tooth](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=743#T=C&C=7)

Comment: @Syberion Interresting... The early Technic gears I'm familiar with are from the 70's. The red (small) , blue (medium) and yellow (big) ones with the white axles. Seems these are even bigger. I had never seen them before.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The rails with the "small teeth" are

[Part No: 3230a ,  Train, Track Tapered Rail Curved Inside](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3230a#T=C)

[Part No: 3229a Name: Train, Track Tapered Rail Curved Outside](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3229a#T=C)

[Part No: 3228a Name: Train, Track Tapered Rail Straight 16L](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3228a#T=C)

Comment: OK - Thanks Syberion.